# wget outputs 3-byte quotation marks

Tags: quoting, wget

I ran a `wget -b`. From the log, I was trying to get the list of files successfully downloaded, and for that I did a `grep saved wget-log | awk -F '"' '{print $2}'` but it didn't work. Further investigation led me to notice that the filename is enclosed in the 3-byte left and right double quotation marks (0xE2 0x80 0x9D), instead of regular double quotation marks (0x22).

Is this wget's normal behaviour, or is it some environment variable on my end, something like that? Can I make wget use regular quotation marks, or use only standard ASCII bytes in its logging, somehow? I know other ways of circumventing it, by substituting the bytes with sed for example. I'm just very intrigued by that: I spent several minutes on google looking for any comments on that and couldn't find anything, it's as if nobody ever had noticed this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be by design in Unicode locales. There's a comment on this on [wget's mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-wget/2012-08/msg00038.html). The language translation files also contain translations for quotes, so you get ‘proper’ quotes according to the language used.

You can make it use regular quotes by using a non-Unicode locale.

```
LC_ALL=C wget ...
```

or

```
LC_CTYPE=C wget ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't found that comment. It seems to explain things, but I don't have any LC_ variable set, and doing your suggestion didn't work. :(

Comment: @msb, hmm, seemed to work for me with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` vs `LC_ALL=C`. What does running `locale` on the command line show?

Comment: oh, you're right. I thought the way to see locales was with `set`. I ran `locale` and got en_US.UTF-8 all around (LANG, LC_CTYPE, LC_COLLATE, etc etc). Except in LC_ALL, which is empty...

Comment: @msb, yep, as far as I understand, `LANG` sets the default, the others are more specific and override it, and `LC_ALL` overrides all the `LC_*` settings.

Comment: idk, maybe it's the opposite and the specifics override the general `LC_ALL`. I just did some experimenting, setting them the way you did (before the command, so not "permanently" changing the environment, but changing the individual variable to C one at a time for each `wget` invocation). It seems `LC_CTYPE` is the one. `LC_ALL`, `LANG` and `LC_MESSAGES` didn't affect the output, but `LC_CTYPE=C wget...` put regular 0x22 quotation marks. Thanks! I added this to your answer. :)

Comment: @msb `LC_ALL` overrides all the others. It's designed precisely for cases like this when you want to get a particular setting regardless of the surrounding environment.

Comment: Except it didn't work.